# PHP advanced search with Multiple OPTION

Tags: php, search, error-handling, query-optimization

I am building a search field with php where users can search for Doctors information with multiple search options.
[image: SEARCH]

As shown in the picture a user can search by: DR.NAME, SPECIALTY, DIVISION, LOCATION. The DR.NAME should match any keyword and the form doesn't require any fields to be filled out.

This is my current code which isn't working.

doctorsearch.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);

    include 'config.php';

    $d_fname = $_POST['d_fname'];
    $d_spcl = $_POST['d_spcl'];
    $d_division = $_POST['d_division'];
    $d_location = $_POST['d_location'];


    $qry = "SELECT * FROM doctor_reg WHERE ";
    if ($d_fname != '') {
        $qry .= "d_fname='".mysql_real_escape_string($d_fname)."' AND ";
    }
    if ($d_spcl != '') {
        $qry .= "d_spcl='".mysql_real_escape_string($d_spcl)."' AND ";
    }
    if ($d_division != '') {
        $qry .= "d_division='".mysql_real_escape_string($d_division)."' AND ";
    }
    if ($d_location != '') {
        $qry .= "d_location='".mysql_real_escape_string($d_location)."' AND ";
    }

    $result = mysql_query($result);

        ?>  

            <?php
            echo "<table border='1px solid #CCCCCC;' width='100%'>";
            echo "<tr style='color:#FFFFFF;background:#555555;'>";
            echo "<th style='padding:3px;'>Name</th>";


            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr class='trbd'>";
            echo "<td style='padding:3px;'>".$row['d_fname'].' '.$row['d_lname']."</td>";

            ?>

            <?php
            echo "</tr>";

    }
            echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Use OR instead of AND in your query

Comment: Tried but still search result empty every time

Comment: try debugging for errors in your query. Also can you paste your formed query here. Also try running the query in phpmyadmin or query prompt for mysql. That will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `OR` instead of `AND`.

Generally, when users search they search by `OR` condition.

For example: Doctor Name should be Sharma or location should be east street.

If we search with `AND` conditions, database will search only records who have the exact combination.

`AND` returns `true` if all the conditions are true.

`OR` returns `true` if any of conditions is true.

Therefore, `OR` is correct syntax here.

**Corrected code:**

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM doctor_reg";
$searchArray = array();
if ($d_fname != '') {
 $searchArray[] = "d_fname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($d_fname) . "%'";
}
if ($d_spcl != '') {
 $searchArray[] = "d_spcl LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($d_spcl) . "%'";
}
if ($d_division != '') {
 $searchArray[] = "d_division LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($d_division) . "%'";
}
if ($d_location != '') {
 $searchArray[] = "d_location LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($d_location) . "%'";
}
$qry .= ! empty($searchArray) ? " WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $searchArray) : '';
```

Comment: For the above array to work, it should be something like `$searchArray[] = 'd_fname LIKE %' . mysql_real_escape_string($d_fname) . '%';`  And for the other array query elements `$searchArray[] = 'd_spcl = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($d_spcl);` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

if you want any keyword not exact match then you shoud use like instead of = operator, so change this

```
if ($d_fname != '') {
    $qry .= "d_fname='".mysql_real_escape_string($d_fname)."' AND ";
}
```

into this

```
if ($d_fname != '') {
    $qry .= "d_fname LIKE'%".mysql_real_escape_string($d_fname)."%' AND ";
}
```